# ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [12] Connecting to an external network is not enabled for this project

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I put the app.yaml under [parse-community](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server) and exec `gcloud app deploy`.

I encountered a error same of this title.

this is my app.yaml

```
service: some-service
runtime: nodejs8
network:
  name: some-network
```

I checked the corresponding data of stackdriver logging, but I did not see any errors that were particularly relevant.

But the service `some-service` exists in GAE services list on GCP Console.

I could access the service's endpoint url `https://**appspot**`.

I need to remove the error when deploying.

Answer (score 3):

The app.yaml's `network` element is only available for the App Engine flexible environment (see doc [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/reference/app-yaml)). As per your app.yaml file, you're trying to deploy your app to the Standard environment.

To deploy on flex, you should update your app.yaml like this:

```
service: some-service
runtime: nodejs8
env: flex
network:
  name: some-network
```